# Form doesn't get submitted in yii2

Tags: php, forms, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-validation

I'm using yii2 advanced app and im stuck at a point where my form doesn't get submitted. It refreshes and stays on the same page. There are no errors shown too.

Here is the model code Countries.php

```
<?php

namespace backend\models\base;

use Yii;
use yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior;
use yii\behaviors\BlameableBehavior;
use mootensai\behaviors\UUIDBehavior;

/**
 * This is the base model class for table "countries".
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $sortname
 * @property string $name
 * @property integer $phonecode
 * @property integer $created_at
 * @property integer $updated_at
 * @property integer $created_by
 * @property integer $updated_by
 * @property integer $deleted_at
 * @property integer $deleted_by
 *
 * @property \backend\models\States[] $states
 */
class Countries extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    use \mootensai\relation\RelationTrait;

    private $_rt_softdelete;
    private $_rt_softrestore;

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->_rt_softdelete = [
            'deleted_by' => \Yii::$app->user->id,
            'deleted_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        ];
        $this->_rt_softrestore = [
            'deleted_by' => 0,
            'deleted_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        ];
    }

    /**
    * This function helps \mootensai\relation\RelationTrait runs faster
    * @return array relation names of this model
    */
    public function relationNames()
    {
        return [
            'states'
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['sortname', 'name', 'phonecode'], 'required'],
            [['phonecode', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'created_by', 'updated_by', 'deleted_at', 'deleted_by'], 'integer'],
            [['sortname'], 'string', 'max' => 3],
            [['name'], 'string', 'max' => 150],
            [['lock'], 'default', 'value' => '0'],
            [['lock'], 'mootensai\components\OptimisticLockValidator']
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'countries';
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return string
     * overwrite function optimisticLock
     * return string name of field are used to stored optimistic lock
     *
     */
    public function optimisticLock() {
        return 'lock';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => Yii::t('app', 'ID'),
            'sortname' => Yii::t('app', 'Sortname'),
            'name' => Yii::t('app', 'Name'),
            'phonecode' => Yii::t('app', 'Phonecode'),
        ];
    }



    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getStates()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\backend\models\States::className(), ['country_id' => 'id']);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     * @return array mixed
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'timestamp' => [
                'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
                'createdAtAttribute' => 'created_at',
                'updatedAtAttribute' => 'updated_at',
                'value' => new \yii\db\Expression('NOW()'),
            ],
            'blameable' => [
                'class' => BlameableBehavior::className(),
                'createdByAttribute' => 'created_by',
                'updatedByAttribute' => 'updated_by',
            ],
            'uuid' => [
                'class' => UUIDBehavior::className(),
                'column' => 'id',
            ],
        ];
    }


    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     * @return \backend\models\query\CountriesQuery the active query used by this AR class.
     */
    public static function find()
    {
        $query = new \backend\models\query\CountriesQuery(get_called_class());
        return $query->where(['countries.deleted_by' => 0]);
    }
}
```

And the controller CountriesController.php

```
<?php

namespace backend\controllers;

use Yii;
use backend\models\Countries;
use backend\models\search\CountriesSearch;
use backend\controllers\BackendController;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;


/**
 * CountriesController implements the CRUD actions for Countries model.
 */
class CountriesController extends BackendController
{
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
            'access' => [
                'class' => \yii\filters\AccessControl::className(),
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'allow' => true,
                        'actions' => ['index', 'view', 'create', 'update', 'delete', 'pdf', 'save-as-new','add-states'],
                        'roles' => ['admin']
                    ],
                    [
                        'allow' => false
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Lists all Countries models.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new CountriesSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Displays a single Countries model.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        $providerStates = new \yii\data\ArrayDataProvider([
            'allModels' => $model->states,
        ]);
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
            'providerStates' => $providerStates,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new Countries model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Countries();

        if ($model->loadAll(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->saveAll()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Updates an existing Countries model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        if (Yii::$app->request->post('_asnew') == '1') {
            $model = new Countries();
        }else{
            $model = $this->findModel($id);
        }

        if ($model->loadAll(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->saveAll()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Deletes an existing Countries model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->findModel($id)->deleteWithRelated();

        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * Export Countries information into PDF format.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionPdf($id) {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);
        $providerStates = new \yii\data\ArrayDataProvider([
            'allModels' => $model->states,
        ]);

        $content = $this->renderAjax('_pdf', [
            'model' => $model,
            'providerStates' => $providerStates,
        ]);

        $pdf = new \kartik\mpdf\Pdf([
            'mode' => \kartik\mpdf\Pdf::MODE_CORE,
            'format' => \kartik\mpdf\Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
            'orientation' => \kartik\mpdf\Pdf::ORIENT_PORTRAIT,
            'destination' => \kartik\mpdf\Pdf::DEST_BROWSER,
            'content' => $content,
            'cssFile' => '@vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/assets/kv-mpdf-bootstrap.min.css',
            'cssInline' => '.kv-heading-1{font-size:18px}',
            'options' => ['title' => \Yii::$app->name],
            'methods' => [
                'SetHeader' => [\Yii::$app->name],
                'SetFooter' => ['{PAGENO}'],
            ]
        ]);

        return $pdf->render();
    }

    /**
    * Creates a new Countries model by another data,
    * so user don't need to input all field from scratch.
    * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
    *
    * @param mixed $id
    * @return mixed
    */
    public function actionSaveAsNew($id) {
        $model = new Countries();

        if (Yii::$app->request->post('_asnew') != '1') {
            $model = $this->findModel($id);
        }

        if ($model->loadAll(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->saveAll()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('saveAsNew', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Finds the Countries model based on its primary key value.
     * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return Countries the loaded model
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    protected function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = Countries::findOne($id)) !== null) {
            return $model;
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException(Yii::t('app', 'The requested page does not exist.'));
        }
    }



    /**
    * Action to load a tabular form grid
    * for States
    * @author Yohanes Candrajaya <moo.tensai@gmail.com>
    * @author Jiwantoro Ndaru <jiwanndaru@gmail.com>
    *
    * @return mixed
    */
    public function actionAddStates()
    {
        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
            $row = Yii::$app->request->post('States');
            if((Yii::$app->request->post('isNewRecord') && Yii::$app->request->post('_action') == 'load' && empty($row)) || Yii::$app->request->post('_action') == 'add')
                $row[] = [];
            return $this->renderAjax('_formStates', ['row' => $row]);
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException(Yii::t('app', 'The requested page does not exist.'));
        }
    }
}
```

and the view file create.php

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;


/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model backend\models\Apps */

$this->title = Yii::t('app', 'Create Apps');
?>
<div class="uk-container uk-container-small uk-position-relative">
    <div><!----> <div>
    <h1 id="navbar" class="uk-h2 tm-heading-fragment">
        <a href="#navbar">Apps</a>
    </h1>

    <!-- Start Breadcrumb -->
    <ul class="uk-breadcrumb">
        <li><?= Html::a('Admin', ['/'])?></li>
        <li><?= Html::a('Apps', ['/apps'])?></li>
        <li>Create</li>
    </ul>
    <!-- End Breadcrumb -->

    <?= $this->render('_form', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]) ?>

</div>
```

and view _form.php

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use alexeevdv\widget\SluggableInputWidget;
use dosamigos\ckeditor\CKEditor;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model backend\models\Apps */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */

?>

<div class="uk-margin-auto">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?= $form->errorSummary($model); ?>


    <?= $form->field($model, 'title')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'placeholder' => 'Title']) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'slug')->widget(SluggableInputWidget::className(), [
        'dependsOn' => 'title',    
    ]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'content')->widget(CKEditor::className(), [
        'options' => ['rows' => 6],
        'preset' => 'basic',
        'clientOptions' => [
            'filebrowserImageBrowseUrl' => yii\helpers\Url::to(['imagemanager/manager', 'view-mode'=>'iframe', 'select-type'=>'ckeditor']),
        ]
    ]);?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'video')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'placeholder' => 'Video']) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'category')->widget(\kartik\widgets\Select2::classname(), [
        'data' => \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(\backend\models\Categories::find()->orderBy('id')->asArray()->all(), 'id', 'name'),
        'options' => ['placeholder' => Yii::t('app', 'Choose a category')],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'allowClear' => true
        ],
    ]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'status')->textInput(['placeholder' => 'Status']) ?>

    <div class="form-group">
    <?php if(Yii::$app->controller->action->id != 'save-as-new'): ?>
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? Yii::t('app', 'Create') : Yii::t('app', 'Update'), ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn uk-button uk-button-primary' : 'btn uk-button uk-button-primary']) ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if(Yii::$app->controller->action->id != 'create'): ?>
        <?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'Save As New'), ['class' => 'btn uk-button uk-button-default', 'value' => '1', 'name' => '_asnew']) ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
        <?= Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Cancel'), Yii::$app->request->referrer , ['class'=> 'btn uk-button uk-button-danger']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

I've browsed few articles, but of no help. My form has a `<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>` at the end of the form. I also tried to remove the select2 widget but i still get the same issue. Could someone help me out why this is happening?

Html output rendered of create.php

```
<div class="uk-container uk-container-small uk-position-relative">
    <div><!----> <div>
    <h1 id="navbar" class="uk-h2 tm-heading-fragment">
        <a href="#navbar">Countries</a>
    </h1>

    <!-- Start Breadcrumb -->
    <ul class="uk-breadcrumb">
        <li><a href="/final/backend/en-us">Admin</a></li>
        <li><a href="/final/backend/en-us/countries">Countries</a></li>
        <li>Create</li>
    </ul>
    <!-- End Breadcrumb -->


<div class="uk-margin-auto">

    <form id="w0" action="/final/backend/en-us/countries/create" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="zIvM0awWY3XpcrF1kY6gFY00ghnL1cgwTYhaEqF7RO2hch4x5AznMwtfWxWp4D-YW9yJy5aiNupb0JnMSbi5qQ==">
    <div class="error-summary" style="display:none"><p>Please fix the following errors:</p><ul></ul></div>
    <div class="form-group field-countries-id">
<input type="text" id="countries-id" class="form-control" name="Countries[id]" style="display:none">
</div>
    <div class="form-group field-countries-sortname required">
<label class="control-label" for="countries-sortname">Sortname</label>
<input type="text" id="countries-sortname" class="form-control" name="Countries[sortname]" maxlength="3" placeholder="Sortname" aria-required="true">

<div class="help-block"></div>
</div>
    <div class="form-group field-countries-name required">
<label class="control-label" for="countries-name">Name</label>
<input type="text" id="countries-name" class="form-control" name="Countries[name]" maxlength="150" placeholder="Name" aria-required="true">

<div class="help-block"></div>
</div>
    <div class="form-group field-countries-phonecode required">
<label class="control-label" for="countries-phonecode">Phonecode</label>
<input type="text" id="countries-phonecode" class="form-control" name="Countries[phonecode]" placeholder="Phonecode" aria-required="true">

<div class="help-block"></div>
</div>
    <div id="w3-container" class=" tabs-above tab-align-left tabs-krajee"><ul id="w3" class="nav nav-tabs nav nav-tabs hidden-print" data-krajee-tabsx="tabsX_0b4b2adf" role="tablist"><li class="active"><a href="#w3-tab0" data-toggle="tab" role="tab"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></i> States</a></li></ul>
<div class="tab-content printable"><div class="h3 visible-print-block"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></i> States</div>
<div id="w3-tab0" class="tab-pane fade in active"><div class="form-group" id="add-states">
<div id="w1" class="grid-view hide-resize" data-krajee-grid="kvGridInit_7fee31f2"><div class="panel panel-default">


    <div class="rc-handle-container" style="width: 628px;"><div class="rc-handle" style="left: 50px; height: 37px;"></div><div class="rc-handle" style="left: 496px; height: 37px;"></div></div><div id="w1-container" class="table-responsive kv-grid-container"><table class="kv-grid-table table table-hover kv-table-wrap"><thead>

<tr><th class="kv-align-center kv-align-middle" style="width: 7.96%;" data-col-seq="0">#</th><th class="kv-align-top kv-grid-hide" data-col-seq="1">Id</th><th class="kv-align-top" data-col-seq="2" style="width: 71.02%;">Name</th><th class="kv-align-middle" data-col-seq="3" style="width: 21.02%;"></th></tr>

</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td colspan="4"><div class="empty">No results found.</div></td></tr>
</tbody></table></div>
    <div class="kv-panel-after"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success kv-batch-create" onclick="addRowStates()"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Add States</button></div>

</div></div>    </div>


</div>
</div></div>    <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="uk-button uk-button-primary">Create</button>                <a class="uk-button uk-button-danger">Cancel</a>    </div>

    </form>
</div>

</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: It would also be useful to show us the html code after the template `create.php` was rendered.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I'm new to stackoverflow so don't know how to add the code to the comments here. Hence i have edited my main question and added the Html rendered.

Comment: You are welcome. If you have big codes, then display them only in questions/answers. The comments are not suitable for multiple code lines ;-)

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks again @aendeerei Any idea why the form isn't getting submitted.

Comment: What happens exactly when you click on Create button?

Comment: And what do you expect to happen?

Comment: And did you checked in web console to see if any javascript errors are raised upon click on Create, which could cancel the submit process?

Comment: You are using loadAll and saveAll in actionCreate. They are part of \mootensai\relation\RelationTrait. Are you sure you don't want to use [load()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#load()-detail) and [save()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#save()-detail)? As I saw the form is fine. It submits to /final/backend/en-us/countries/create. Is it the correct path - to the actionCreate() in CountriesController? Before loading and saving you should check the $_POST values, because I think the loading or the saving have some problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing loadAll() and saveAll() to load() and save() has solved the issue

```
<?php

namespace backend\controllers;

use Yii;
use backend\models\Countries;
use backend\models\search\CountriesSearch;
use backend\controllers\BackendController;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;

/**
 * CountriesController implements the CRUD actions for Countries model.
 */
class CountriesController extends BackendController
{
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
            'access' => [
                'class' => \yii\filters\AccessControl::className(),
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'allow' => true,
                        'actions' => ['index', 'view', 'create', 'update', 'delete', 'pdf', 'save-as-new','add-states'],
                        'roles' => ['admin']
                    ],
                    [
                        'allow' => false
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Lists all Countries models.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new CountriesSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Displays a single Countries model.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        $providerStates = new \yii\data\ArrayDataProvider([
            'allModels' => $model->states,
        ]);
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
            'providerStates' => $providerStates,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new Countries model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Countries();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Updates an existing Countries model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        if (Yii::$app->request->post('_asnew') == '1') {
            $model = new Countries();
        }else{
            $model = $this->findModel($id);
        }

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Deletes an existing Countries model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->findModel($id)->deleteWithRelated();

        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * Export Countries information into PDF format.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionPdf($id) {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);
        $providerStates = new \yii\data\ArrayDataProvider([
            'allModels' => $model->states,
        ]);

        $content = $this->renderAjax('_pdf', [
            'model' => $model,
            'providerStates' => $providerStates,
        ]);

        $pdf = new \kartik\mpdf\Pdf([
            'mode' => \kartik\mpdf\Pdf::MODE_CORE,
            'format' => \kartik\mpdf\Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
            'orientation' => \kartik\mpdf\Pdf::ORIENT_PORTRAIT,
            'destination' => \kartik\mpdf\Pdf::DEST_BROWSER,
            'content' => $content,
            'cssFile' => '@vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/assets/kv-mpdf-bootstrap.min.css',
            'cssInline' => '.kv-heading-1{font-size:18px}',
            'options' => ['title' => \Yii::$app->name],
            'methods' => [
                'SetHeader' => [\Yii::$app->name],
                'SetFooter' => ['{PAGENO}'],
            ]
        ]);

        return $pdf->render();
    }

    /**
    * Creates a new Countries model by another data,
    * so user don't need to input all field from scratch.
    * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
    *
    * @param mixed $id
    * @return mixed
    */
    public function actionSaveAsNew($id) {
        $model = new Countries();

        if (Yii::$app->request->post('_asnew') != '1') {
            $model = $this->findModel($id);
        }

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('saveAsNew', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Finds the Countries model based on its primary key value.
     * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return Countries the loaded model
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    protected function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = Countries::findOne($id)) !== null) {
            return $model;
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException(Yii::t('app', 'The requested page does not exist.'));
        }
    }



    /**
    * Action to load a tabular form grid
    * for States
    * @author Yohanes Candrajaya <moo.tensai@gmail.com>
    * @author Jiwantoro Ndaru <jiwanndaru@gmail.com>
    *
    * @return mixed
    */
    public function actionAddStates()
    {
        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
            $row = Yii::$app->request->post('States');
            if((Yii::$app->request->post('isNewRecord') && Yii::$app->request->post('_action') == 'load' && empty($row)) || Yii::$app->request->post('_action') == 'add')
                $row[] = [];
            return $this->renderAjax('_formStates', ['row' => $row]);
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException(Yii::t('app', 'The requested page does not exist.'));
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you @aendeerei for the quick help!

Comment: You are welcome ;-) I'm glad that it works and that I could be of help. Don't forget to also mark your answer as "accepted" (use the check icon under the arrows on the left), so that the other users can benefit from it too. Good luck.